# Display number as a date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm trying to display a variable in SQL Developer as a date (Preferrably something like 2017/01/05).
If I query:

```
select raw_date from src_table where rownum < 2
```

I get a number:

```
61340
```

From the query below, I found that the source date has type=2, which I see is either a number or a float. I assume because Len=4 and there's no decimal that it's a number rather than a float.

```
select dump(raw_date) from src_table
where rownum < 2;
```

```
Typ=2 Len=4: 195,7,14,41
```

I've tried casting to date and using the to_date function, but no luck so far. When I try:

```
select to_date(raw_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd') as my_date from src_table
```

I get:

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

I assume my syntax is off. Am I close?

Comment: `61340` can represent a lot of things (to add more to the mix, an Excel date from year 2067 —Windows— or 2071 —Mac—). You really need to know the expected output or you'll just be guessing.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Excel 16.16.25 on my MacBook gives 2067-12-09.

Comment: @sobrio35 can you not get the standard definition for the column using right-click or by querying `user_tab_columns` (or `all_tab_columns` if the table is in another schema)? It's a `number`, though. `float` is just a subtype of `number` that in the entire history or Oracle, nobody has ever used.

Comment: @sobrio35 . . . You need to ask whoever designed or owns the database.  What you have is a number and there are close to an infinite number of ways it could be mapped to a date.  For instance, it could represent 2040-06-13 or 1940-06-13.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thanks for the feedback (I'm not a Mac user). The PC/Mac 1900/1904 issue is well known but I admit I don't know what exact systems if affects or what exact symptoms it produces.

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect to get as a result for 61340?

Numbers that represents dates *might* be Julian dates; in that case:

```
SQL> select to_date(61340, 'j') from dual;

TO_DATE(61
----------
10.12.4545

SQL>
```

but - this value doesn't make much sense. 4545 year? Huh?

Vice versa (date to a Julian date) returns

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'j') from dual;

TO_CHAR
-------
2459095

SQL>
```

If you know what that 61340 represents, it would be easier to assist.

Answer (score 1):

If the value corresponds to the day number, i.e. one higher number is the next day, you may try sometnihg like this

```
select DATE'1800-01-01' + 61340 dt from dual;

DT                 
-------------------
12.12.1967 00:00:00
```

Substitute the initial date with a propper value